# Count block of time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I've been at this for days and so stuck! They want to know how many AM, PM and Evening sessions in April and how many total visits for the sessions

i.e. 
Month: April
ct_AM_sess 19, #Visits 38
ct_PM_sess 21, #Visits 116
ct_Eve_sess 4, #Visits 23

I've tried to do it Crystal and even moved the data to excel.

```
select resourceid, ApptStart,datename(m,ApptStart) as daymonth,datename(dd,ApptStart) as day, 
datename(yy,ApptStart) as year, count(AppointmentsId) As Visits,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, ApptStart) BETWEEN 0 AND 12 THEN 'AM' END AS 'MORNING_SESSION',
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, ApptStart) BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN 'PM' END AS 'AFTERNOON_SESSION',
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, ApptStart) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 'EVE' END AS 'EVENING_SESSION'
from appointments
where Resourceid = '50' and 
datename(m,ApptStart) = 'April' and datename(yy,ApptStart) = '2014' --using timeframe for sample data
and status in ('Arrived','Completed')
group by resourceid, ApptStart,datename(m,ApptStart),datename(dd,ApptStart),datename(yy,ApptStart)
```

Comment: What is the difference between a visit and a session in this scenario?

Comment: Each session has a number of visits within it.  i.e. provider has an AM session (between 8-12) on a particular day and then the number of appt slots (visits) within the session

Answer (score 0):

do a count on your case statements then groupy by whatever you need, this will give you a count on sessions since you didnt really let us know how to differenciate between visits and sessions

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, min(ApptStart)) BETWEEN 0 AND 12 THEN count(distinct appointmentid) END AS 'MORNING_SESSION',
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, min(ApptStart)) BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN count(distinct appointmentid) END AS 'AFTERNOON_SESSION',
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, min(ApptStart)) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN count(distinct appointmentid) END AS 'EVENING_SESSION'
```

Comment: Thanks, my explanation is above, I've tried this option before and this will count each block of time.

So provider 50 has appts from 8:00 - 12 in 15 minute increments...so 8:00-8:15, 8:15-8:30 etc...the block of time between 8-12 is the AM session, then they want the number of visits within that session...PM session would be 12-5 and the number of visits in that timeframe...I need to find the number of sessions in the month and the number of visits within the sessions...does that help?

Comment: @user3658115 can you post some sample data up?

Comment: @user3658115 have you tried to add min to apptstart and count distinct appt id's?

query above changed

Comment: Sample data is above in my original post.

Comment: @user3658115 you have a query, no data